# Autofill Postcode/Zip Field in Estimate Shipping and VAT

Tags: magento2, shipping-address, shipping-estimate

As part of a project I am working on, I need to set the customers postcode using localStorage anywhere on the site to allow other postcode functionality to occur.

Part of this is to also autofill the Estimate Shipping and VAT Postcode field so rates are shown straight away. By default magento populates if the customer is logged in so this is fine.

Can anyone point me in the correct direction to get the Postcode Field auto populated based on a session variable or localStorage variable?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really have answers for that but what I would have tried would have been to search for the `collectRatesByAddress` method calls.
This is the methods that populates the shipping methods using the data like postcode send in the form.

As you wan't to populate this informations directly from the customer address (assuming he has one). I would say that you need somehow to replicate that method but instead of taking the data from the request you will take it from the session (we can know the current customer so we know his address that's not an issue).

I'm not sure about magento steps but lets say the delivery form is step 2 in checkout.

What I would have try to do is in step 1 validation trigger an ajax call that would have trigger your customer collectRatesByAdress.

Now that's the theory, I don't really know how to plug all that with the checkout javascript datas, there might be some js additionnal parts...but thats the direction I would have take from my newbie level if this was a feature I had to make.